# r-How to add column in r

Tags: r

I have data table

```
Name   Score
A      5
A      6
B      9
B      1
B      0
...
```

I want  to calculate and add a column 'FScore'=max score to this table

My expected result

```
Name  Score Fscore
A      5     6
A      6     6
B      9     9
B      1     9
B      0     9
```

Thank.

Comment: `ave(df$Score, df$Name, FUN = max)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the maximum score for each Name value, you can use data.table as below.

```
# example data
d <- data.table(Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
                Score = c(5, 6, 9, 1, 0))
# find max for each Name and save the value in a new column, Fscore
d[ , Fscore := max(Score), by=Name]
```

Result:

```
> print(d)
   Name Score Fscore
1:    A     5      6
2:    A     6      6
3:    B     9      9
4:    B     1      9
5:    B     0      9
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the base `R` option `ave`

```
df$Fscore <- ave(df$Score, df$Name, FUN = max)
df
#   Name Score Fscore
#1    A     5      6
#2    A     6      6
#3    B     9      9
#4    B     1      9
#5    B     0      9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `dplyr` could be:

```
df = data.frame(Name = c('a', 'a', 'b','b','b'), Score = c(5,6,9,1,0))

df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Fscore = max(Score))

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: Name [2]

    Name Score FScore
  <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1      a     5      6
2      a     6      6
3      b     9      9
4      b     1      9
5      b     0      9
```